# Dropzone add existing files

Tags: knockout.js, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone with knockout. I want to add existing files to dropzone. My dropzone custom binding code is (Only see the code to add existing files as adding new files is working fine):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dropzone = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

                var options = {
                    maxFileSize: 15,
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    parallelUploads: 100,
                    maxFiles: 30,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                    init: function () {
                        var myDropzone = this;
                        this.on("success", function (file, serverFileName) {
                            fileList = [];
                            i = 1;
                            var abc = $.map(serverFileName, function (item) { return (item); });
                            $.each(abc, function (index, value) {
                                fileList[i] = { "fileName": value, "fileId": i++ };
                            })
                        });
                        if (images) {
                            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { //data in images array is shown in figure
                                myDropzone.emit("addedfile", images[i]);
                                myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", images[i], "/Images/Ads/");
                                myDropzone.emit("complete", images[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                $.extend(options, value);

                $(element).addClass('dropzone');
                new Dropzone(element, options); 
            }
        };
```

The data in `images` array is :

[image: data in images array]

And my HTML code is :

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" data-bind="dropzone: { url: '/Electronics/FileUploadHandler' }"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <h2>Add Images</h2>
   <div id="dropzonePreview" class="dz-default dz-message"> </div>
</form>
```

Now the added existing images are shown in figure.
[image]

Why the thumbnail of images are not displayed? And when i hover over "Remove file" the link that appears on browser's bottom left side is `javascript:undefined;`. And when I click "Remove file" the file is removed but "Drop images to upload" is shown which should only be visible when there are no images in dropzone. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: it all depends on how you have configured your mock file!

Answer (score 4):

I can only answer to the part of the question:

> And when I click "Remove file" the file is removed but "Drop images to upload" is shown which should only be visible when there are no images in dropzone. What i am doing wrong?

Found that after you emitted events to add existing files to dropzone, you need to add entry to the files array (dropzone checks number of entries in that array, and if it is zero - shows "Drop images to upload" message:

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", images[i]);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", images[i], "/Images/Ads/");
myDropzone.emit("complete", images[i]);
myDropzone.files.push(images[i]); // added this line
```

It's very confusing this question from 2015 is unanswered and example on the dropzone site still have this problem...

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track! Another quirk is that you'll need to set `accepted: true` (and likely also `status: 'success'`) on each file that you add this way. Otherwise, Dropzone won't count the existing files against any max file limit you may have set. In my case, I have a limit of a single file, so if one already exists the user shouldn't be able to add another one. Without setting `accepted: true`, Dropzone would allow adding one more file. The official sample says to manually adjust the maxFiles setting, but leaving that as is and using the standard logic feels cleaner to me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to register event 'removedfile' and do a server call to 'physicaly' remove file on server.

```
var options = {
                ...
                init: function () {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    ...
                    // Register removedfile event
                    myDropzone.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                      // Ajax call to your server for remove a file
                      $.ajax({
                        url : 'your/del/file/url',
                        data : {paramName : file.name}
                      }).done({
                        // Remove successfully
                      });
                    });
                }
}
```